# At which point adding new data to a training set, will not improve training accuracy

Tags: deep-learning, conv-neural-network, training-data, yolo

This is more a general question about training a CNN but the one i'm using is YOLO. 
I've started my training set for 'person' detections by labelling some data from different cameras videos (in similar environment).... Every time I was adding new data for a new camera I was retraining YOLO, which actually improved the detection for this camera. For the training, I split my data randomly into training/validation set. I use the validation set to compute accuracy. This is not overfitting as all the previous data are also used in the training.

Now, I've gathered more than 100 000 labelled data. I was expecting to not have to train anymore at this point as my data set is pretty big. But looks like I still need to do it. if i'm getting a new camera video, labelling 500-1000 samples, adding them to my huge data set and training again, the accuracy is improving for this camera.
I don't understand really understand why. Why do i still need to add new data to my set? Why is the accuracy improving a lot on the new data, while there are 'drawn' in the thousands of already existing data? Is there a point where I will be able to stop training because adding new data will not improve the accuracy?

Thanks for sharing your thoughts and ideas!

Answer (score 1):

Interesting question. If your data quality is good and the training procedure is 'perfect' you will always be able to generalize better. Think about all the possible infite different images that you will want to detect. You are only using a sample of that, hoping that it is enough to generalize. You can keep increasing your dataset and might gain a 0.01% more, the question is when you want to stop. Your model accuracy will never be 100%.

My opinion: if you have a nice above 95% of accuracy stop generating more data if your project is personal and no one's life depends on it. Think about post processing to improve the results. Since you are detecting on video maybe try to follow the person movement so if in one frame it is not detected and you have info from the previous and posterior frame you might be able to do something fancy.

Hope it helps, cheers!

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It's actually my job and we get new customers every time, with new cameras etc... I guess i'm just surprise of the power of CNN, and how it can still learn and take into account the new data i'm giving it each time!

Comment: Nice! Then never stop improving accuracy until is not worth the money to do so!

Answer (score 0):

To create a good model of course you will need as many images as possible. But you have to pay attention whether your model become **overfit**, which is your model is not learning anymore and the **average loss** getting higher and the **mAP** getting lower, when overfitting occurs you have to stop the training and choose the best weight that has been saved in darknet/backup/ folder.

For YOLO, there are some guidelines that you can follow about when you should to stop training. The most obvious is :

During training, you will see varying indicators of error, and you should stop when no longer decreases **0.XXXXXXX** avg:

```
Region Avg IOU: 0.798363, Class: 0.893232, Obj: 0.700808, No Obj: 0.004567, Avg Recall: 1.000000, count: 8 Region Avg IOU: 0.800677, Class: 0.892181, Obj: 0.701590, No Obj: 0.004574, Avg Recall: 1.000000, count: 8

9002: 0.211667, 0.060730 avg, 0.001000 rate, 3.868000 seconds, 576128 images Loaded: 0.000000 seconds
```

9002 - iteration number (number of batch)
0.060730 avg - **average loss (error)** - the lower, the better

When you see that average loss 0.xxxxxx avg no longer decreases at many iterations then you should stop training. The final average loss can be from 0.05 (for a small model and easy dataset) to 3.0 (for a big model and a difficult dataset). I personally think that model with avg loss 0.06 is good enough.

AlexeyAB explained everything in detail on his github repo, read this section please https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet#when-should-i-stop-training

Comment: Thanks for you reply. I know when to stop a particular training. But my question wasn't really when to stop a training but when to not have to train anymore. Meaning all my data should cover all the objects I want to detect in any similar environment..

Comment: I guess there's no limitation for that, correct me if I'm wrong. Because deep learning model is always can be improved, I never heard such indicator that tells you to stop adding more data and stop the training process.

Comment: Yes, there i no indicator I guess I more asking about people knowledge and experience!